# Gostaria de deixar minha URL amigável em .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável

Olá, estou tentando de várias formas tentando deixar a minha URL mais amigável porém não estou conseguindo deixar, ela esta assim:

http://meusite.com/single-product.php?aff_ext=1000&categoria=77&produto=548829

Gostaria de deixar ela assim:

http://meusite.com/single-product.php/sansung-galaxy-s6-4g

Com o exemplo acima eu gostaria de tirar todos aqueles GETs e trocar pelo nome do produto, porém para pegar a página de descrição do produto eu preciso dos GETs. Preciso de algo que camuflasse a URL apenas no navegador do usuário

Comment: Mas no caso terei varias categorias e varios produtos se eu for fazer 1 pra cada um não teria como

Answer (score 1):

para o que você deseja as configurações de apache no seu `.htaccess` são as menores dificuldades que você terá, em recomendo o desenvolvimento de um pequeno sistema de MVC.

Para isto recomendo o seguinte link:
[Criando um mini-framework PHP 5 com MVC](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj86o-9943LAhWDC5AKHc0yCB4QtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F17718083&usg=AFQjCNFzYknWDQFZ1idcE1NxMVtpcTJ7kw&sig2=86I7NraBGzS-5Y1JeCQ6EA)

Créditos para nosso colega Matheus Moura, que nesta série de vídeos ensina muito bem, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro foi muito útil, Deus abençoe vc!!!